# Cómo evitar el PostBack para que no se cierre una ventana

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Tengo un `GridView` donde cargo los datos del usuario, al seleccionar uno levanta el Panel a través de un `ModalPopupExtender`, este panel tiene `UpdatePanel` anidados como pueden ver en el código, al presionar el botón guardar cierra el *Popup*, no encuentro el error, me ayudan con este problema.

Al quitar el `UpdatePanel` del `FileUpload` no deja subir el archivo pero ya no se cierra el *Popup*, pero yo necesito subir el archivo y que no se cierre el *Popup*.

```html
<asp:Panel ID="pDatos" runat="server" BackColor="#E0E0E0">
 <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvResultado" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                           OnRowCommand="gvResultado_OnRowCommand" DataKeyNames="Id, Estado" >
                   <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="Id" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Black"
                                         ControlStyle-CssClass="hover" CommandName="gvResultado"
                                         HeaderText="Verificar"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" ItemStyle-Width="320px" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Observaciones" HeaderText="Observaciones" ItemStyle-Width="360px" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fecha" HeaderText="Fecha" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Estado" HeaderText="Estado" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
                   </Columns>
               </asp:GridView>
            </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfPopup" runat="server" />

<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpePopup" runat="server" PopupControlID="pPopup"
                         TargetControlID="hfPopup" BackgroundCssClass="backgroundColor">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pPopup" runat="server" BackColor="#CFCFCF" Style="display: none" >
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPopup" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table style="width:740px;" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvHistorial" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                      OnRowCommand="gvHistorial_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="Descargar" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Legajo" HeaderText="Legajo" ItemStyle-Width="100"/>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Observaciones" HeaderText="Observaciones" ItemStyle-Width="550" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fecha" HeaderText="Fecha" ItemStyle-Width="150"/>
                                <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="Descargar" HeaderText="Descargar" CommandName="gvHistorial_Descargar" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><!-- --></td>
                    <td >
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upArchivo" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="luSeleccione" runat="server" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                           <Triggers>
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="bGuardar" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><!-- --></td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGuardar" OnClick="btnGuardar_Click"
                                    Text="Guardar" CssClass="Button hover" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSalir" OnClick="btnSalir_Click"
                                    Text="Salir" CssClass="Button hover" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta volver abrir el modal con `mpePopup.Show` en el evento del botón guardar

Comment: Alonso revisa por favor: [answer]. Tienes suficiente reputación para realizar comentarios, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En el evento que se ejecuta en el `code behind` vuelve a mostrar el modal:

```
protected void btnSubirArchivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Código ejecutado
   mpePopup.Show();
}
```

En este [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/474/) podrás ver cómo funciona y finalmente se muestra el modal.